# Unable to login to sandbox Salesforce system - Error: Check for an invalid assertion in the SAML Assertion

Tags: salesforce

Getting error when I browse to my salesforce sandbox URL:

> We can't log you in. Check for an invalid assertion in the SAML
>   Assertion Validator (available in Single Sign-On Settings) or check
>   the login history for failed logins.

I don't get to a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to [test.salesforce.com](http://test.salesforce.com) and login from that page.